# Adding delay between shots

Tags: c++

Here is the my code, I call the function shooting each loop in main. This results in a lot of a really high rate of fire. I wish to add some delay to get a RoF of maybe 2-3/s but the only way I know how to do it delays my entire loop.

```
void game::shooting(){

if (P->shoot()){
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   VGCVector der = VGCVector (-5+5*i,5);
   VGCVector hit = P->getPos();
   VGCVector calib = VGCVector (10,0);
   hit= hit+calib;
  SV.push_back(shot(hit,der,false));
  }


}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( NextShootTime < CurrentTime )
{
  Shoot();
  NextShootTime = CurrentTime + ShootDelay;
}
```

Initialise NextShootTime to 0 and you're set.

You may also want to handle queuing up multiple bullets in one frame in case the framerate is very low.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the time of the frame and check this against the intended rate of fire.